# How is attention involved with the performance drop associated with multi-tasking?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, performance, attention

Multi-tasking lowers productivity.

**What influences on attention cause the productivity of a multi-tasking person to be low?**

An example of multi-tasking is that a person is working on his assignment while trying to memorize unfamilar Spanish words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important factor to consider is whether the separate tasks involve the same kind of mental process. For instance, among these multi-tasking scenarios:

1. `listen to someone` and `read something at the same time`
2. `listen to someone` and `walk`
3. `walk` and `read something at the same time`

$\#1$ is generally harder than $\#2$, partly because both of its tasks involve linguistic processing, whereas walking does not.

$\#2$ might be a somewhat unfair example at first glance, because walking is also more self-contained and automatic on flat ground. On uneven ground, however, $\#3$ would be much harder than $\#2$, because both walking and reading require visual processing in such circumstances. This point implicates automaticity and difficulty as (probably related) influential factors as well. I'm sure there are others, and I hope others will help fill in other ideas.